# Locking SQLite database file during backup

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization, backup, android-sqlite

I am trying to implement a service to backup the SQLite database of my Android app. I am planning to both schedule this service for frequent backups (every day for example), and add an option to launch it immediately.

My problem is that the service might start while the application is running, or the user might start the application while the backup is in progress. And they may write to the database while I am copying it.

Is there any way to make sure that the copy and write will not run concurrently, **without adding synchronization locks to all my queries** ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using explicit transactions, SQLite will automatically use a transaction around each SQL statement.

To ensure that the database files cannot be accessed by another database connection while you are doing the backup, open an [exclusive transaction](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) around the backup.

Comment: That's what I needed; the backup API may be a better option, but not usable easily in my case

Answer (score 1):

`SQLite` site [has some notes](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) on doing hot backup on a running database. See the `Example 2` in that page.

In android, if you want to initiate a file copy of your sqlite db file, you will first need to get a `shared lock` as mentioned above, but this approach has shortcomings.

Ideally, you would want to use the sqlite3_backup_* apis.

These APIs are not available in standard android sqlite API, but [it is easy to copy the `sqlite jni` code to your project](http://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki), and expose these additional features. The advantage with this approach is that you dont have to change existing API calls in your code, as it mirrors existing android sqlite API definitions.

To expose backup APIs, take a look at [`android_database_SQLiteConnection.cpp`](http://www.sqlite.org/android/artifact/cd31d02c61957f9c8b708131ddd1fbf0c16711f7) to see how existing JNI functions call the native sqlite_* APIs.

Another option is to use something [like sqlite4java](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/), it has the [sqlite backup APIs wrapped in as Java](http://almworks.com/sqlite4java/javadoc/com/almworks/sqlite4java/SQLiteBackup.html) APIs, and seems the [latest version supports Android](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/).

Comment: Nice information, thanks ! This definitely looks like the way to go for a sqlite database; even though it is a bit difficult on Android. But in fact I am using an SQLCipher database, which makes applying this a little harder.